# Get Server Name in TCP Server

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, hostname, domain-name

Is it possible to get the server address used by a TCP client? A client can reach the server using either IP address or host/domain name.

I'm trying to get the domain name using:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket s = ss.accept();
System.out.println(s.getLocalAddress().getHostName());
System.out.println(s.getLocalAddress().getCanonicalHostName());
```

but all I get is IP address, always!

In an HTTP server, we can achieve the same using `httpServletRequest.getServerName()`. It returns IP address if the HTTP client uses IP address and it returns domain name if the HTTP client uses domain name. So I'm quite sure it should be possible at TCP level also.

Comment: [If you read the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName()), you'll see that getServerName(..) is not read from something at TCP level. Its actually read from `Host: yourServer.com` header that is sent as a part of your HTTP Request. Down at the TCP level, you only have IP addresses, and your best bet is to **try** to resolve them to hostnames (the way you are doing now).

Answer (score 0):

if you tried your `LocalHost` as a server it will probably bring back the name, it might be a DNS problem tho; anyway try you `localhost` as a server and if it worked go to `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and define your host names.

[check this out.](http://www.circleid.com/posts/20090408_why_dns_is_broken_part_1_trust/)

hope this will help.

Comment: sorry, this does not help. I do not want to resolve the hostname. My server can be reached using a wild card domain name, and I want to identify the name like subdomain1.mydomain.com, subdomain2.mydomain.com, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to find out on server - which IP address was used by 'client' to connect to server, when server is listening on multiple IP Addresses. Is this your question? In that cases doing `getsockname()` on `accept`ed socket should give you.

Comment: Yes, you understood my question correctly. But there is no method like `getsockname` in the Socket class.

Comment: Isn't the getLocalAddress or getLocalSocketAddress giving you what you want?

Comment: It is impossible to get that @ TCP level. TCP level is unaware of the 'name resolution process'. TCP connection establishment happens - after name is resolved and client receives an IP address for the name it asked. So obviously that name cannot be seen @ TCP level. As someone pointed out HTTP Server: is your best bet.